# No Overlay widget found when MaterialApp widget present

Tags: flutter, dart

The following is a complete app and a bare-bones reproduction of an issue I am having. It has two screens - a home screen and a second screen. The pages share some common elements - in this case just a simple back navigation button. Instead of adding these elements to each screen manually I want to wrap each screen in a Screen widget from within the MaterialApp builder.

Why does the following work:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: HomeScreen.routePath,
      routes: {
        HomeScreen.routePath: (_) => HomeScreen(),
        SecondScreen.routePath: (_) => SecondScreen(),
      },
      builder: (context, child) => child ?? Container(),
    );
  }
}

class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const Screen(Widget widget) : child = widget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Stack(children: [
        child,
        const Positioned(
          top: 32,
          left: 32,
          child: BackButton(color: Colors.deepPurple),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routePath = "/";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Screen(Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text("Go to other screen"),
          onPressed: () =>
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SecondScreen.routePath),
        ),
      ));
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routePath = "/second";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      const Screen(Center(child: Text("The second screen")));
}
```

But if I make these small changes and move the Screen widget up into the MaterialApp builder (see comments) I get an error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: HomeScreen.routePath,
      routes: {
        HomeScreen.routePath: (_) => HomeScreen(),
        SecondScreen.routePath: (_) => SecondScreen(),
      },
      builder: (context, child) =>
          Screen(child ?? Container()), // wrap the Screen widget here
    );
  }
}

class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const Screen(Widget widget) : child = widget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Stack(children: [
        child,
        const Positioned(
          top: 32,
          left: 32,
          child: BackButton(color: Colors.deepPurple),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routePath = "/";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => /* instead of here */ Center(  
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text("Go to other screen"),
          onPressed: () =>
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SecondScreen.routePath),
        ),
      );
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routePath = "/second";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      const /* and instead of here */ Center(child: Text("The second screen"));
}
```

The error I receive is

```
No Overlay widget found.

Tooltip widgets require an Overlay widget ancestor for correct operation.

The most common way to add an Overlay to an application is to include a 
MaterialApp or Navigator widget in the runApp() call.
```

Why does the MaterialApp widget not count as an ancestor to the Screen widget returned from the builder?